# Using where clause with join in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

im receiving syntax error on it, getting problem while working with join in C#? Here is my code:

```
DataTable dtProducts = system.GetDataTable ("SELECT p.*, c.CategoryName, sc.CategoryName as SubCategoryName
                                             FROM TBLPRODUCTS p 
                                             LEFT JOIN TBLCATEGORIES c ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId 
                                             LEFT JOIN TBLCATEGORIES sc ON c.SubCategoryId = sc.CateogryId
                                             WHERE p.ProductID == ProductID");
```

Comment: in your sql where string are coming two times. please remove one where string.

Comment: You've got a C# syntax error simply because you've got line breaks in a regular string literal. Use a verbatim string literal `@"Select ..."` instead. It's not clear whether "I'm receiving syntax error" means a compilation error (the one I've described) or an exception due to SQL syntax. Please include the *exact* error message in your question.

Comment: Also change  `p.ProductID == ProductID` to `p.ProductID =ProductID` in where clause

Comment: This is not a question about the C# language, but rather SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use only one time equal sign

```
where p.ProductID == ProductID
```

change to

```
where p.ProductID = ProductID
```

also remove second where

Answer (score 1):

You repeated the `WHERE` clause two times

```
 where 
     where p.ProductID == ProductID
```

Plus you should use `=` instead of `==` in this `WHERE` clause.

Finally you should add the `@` symbol in front of a string to form a [verbatim string literal](http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-51752_The_Chash_String_Literal.aspx):

It should read:

```
DataTable dtProducts = system.GetDataTable (@"Select 
        p.*, c.CategoryName, sc.CategoryName as SubCategoryName
    from 
        TBLPRODUCTS p 
    left join
        TBLCATEGORIES c on p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId 
    left join
        TBLCATEGORIES sc on c.SubCategoryId = sc.CateogryId
    where 
        p.ProductID = ProductID");
```

Comment: need to add the @ infront of the string for multiline